# How can I delete lines above string

Tags: c++, string, ifstream, getline, ofstream

How would I be able to delete a line above a string? For example i'm opening a text file and editing it. The way my program works is the user inputs a teachers name. "Mr. John Doe" Then it deletes the next 7 lines from the name searched. Looks for everything in between "Courses" and "endInstructor" and deletes it, but what is left is the two strings above the name that was searched which is "loginpw123" and "startInstructor".

Now my question is how would I delete those two lines after everything else is removed, because it's different for every professor and the list has about 20 profiles on it.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile("instructor.csv");
    ofstream myfile2("outfile.csv");
    string line;
    string dropInstructor;
    bool notFound = false;

    cout << "Enter Instructor to drop by name: ";
    getline(cin, dropInstructor);

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line != dropInstructor)
        {
            myfile2 << line << endl;
        }

        if (line == dropInstructor)
        {
            myfile2 << "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            {
                getline(myfile, line);
                myfile2 << "";
            }
            getline(myfile, line);
            if (line == "Courses:")
            {
                myfile2 << "";
                while (getline(myfile, line))
                {
                    if (line == "endInstructor")
                    {
                        myfile2 << "";
                        break;
                    }
                    myfile2 << "tempp";
                }

                /*for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    getline(myfile, line);
                    myfile2 << "";
                }*/
            }
        }
    }

    /*if (!notFound)
    {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
        cin.get();
        // client ->sendToClient("Not Found");
    }*/

    myfile.close();
    myfile2.close();

    remove("instructor.csv");
    rename("outfile.csv", "instructor.csv");

}
```

---

text file:

```
loginpw123
startInstructor
Mr. John Doe
755 Teacher St
532 791 3761
johndoe@schoolname.ca
392817
03/02/1988
Male
777777
Courses:
Courseinfo1
Courseinfo2
Courseinfo3
Courseinfo4
Courseinfo5
endInstructor
```

Comment: 1. Read lines into vector of strings. 2. Remove lines. 3. Write contents of vector back to file replacing the entirety of its original content.

Comment: What is your specific C++ question? If you already developed a logical algorithm for implementing this, but are not sure how to translate some part of it into C++, then you should post all the code that you have written so far, and explain what you're missing. If you don't know how to come up with a logical algorithm for implementing this, your question has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have the code already, i'll update it now with it. I figured I shouldn't post the code cause didn't want to seem like I wanted it to get done for me. But i'll update it now.

Comment: If you already know how to find the professor's name, and you know there are always 2 lines above that name, then what is the actual problem? The only way to remove lines from a text file is to write to a new file, copying lines you want to keep and omitting lines you want to remove. So take note of the index of the professor''s name, decrement it by 2, and then omit everything from that index to the `endProfessor` line.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thats what I was thinking, but honestly this may sound stupid but I didn't know how to implement the decrement into what I already have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the first two lines to the new file before you have determined whether or not they belong to the professor that is being removed (why is the line above `startProfessor` not between `startProfessor`/`endProfessor` instead?).  You need to save the first line in memory temporarily, then check the professor, and if not a match then write all lines related to the professor to the new file.

Try something like this:

```
int main()
{
    ifstream myfile("instructor.csv");
    ofstream myfile2("outfile.csv");

    string line, lineAboveProfessor;
    string dropInstructor;
    bool ignore = false, found = false;

    cout << "Enter Instructor to drop by name: ";
    getline(cin, dropInstructor);

    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        if (line == "startInstructor")
        {
            if (!getline(myfile, line))
                break;

            ignore = (line == dropProfessor);
            if (ignore)
            {
                found = true;
            }
            else
            {
                myfile2 << lineAboveProfessor << endl
                        << "startInstructor" << endl
                        << line << endl;
            }

            while (getline(myfile, line))
            {
                if (!ignore)
                    myfile2 << line << endl;

                if (line == "endProfessor")
                {
                    if (!ignore)
                        myfile2 << endl;
                    break;
                }
            }

            lineAboveProfessor = "";
        }
        else
        {
            lineAboveProfessor = line;
        }
    }

    /*if (!found)
    {
        cout << "Not found" << endl;
        cin.get();
        // client ->sendToClient("Not Found");
    }*/

    if (myfile1.eof() && myfile2.good())
    {
        myfile.close();
        myfile2.close();

        remove("instructor.csv");
        rename("outfile.csv", "instructor.csv");    
    }
    else
    {
        myfile.close();
        myfile2.close();

        remove("outfile.csv");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, your method works I actually didn't think about temporarily storing the line in memory. I have to do the same method for dropping courses and students so will do same thing. Thanks!

Comment: I Just implemented what you helped me on,  but there needs to be a space in between the user profiles, I tried adding myfile2 << endl; after the second while loop, but it creates two newlines instead of one. Any idea how I can correct this? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidA it should be inside the inner while loop, not outside of it. I have updated my example.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! I had to run it through the debugger to understand what exactly was happening, I got confused a bit I guess thats why I missed t.